# Code HTML doesn't work in Javascript

Tags: html, cordova, contacts

am trying to organize list of contacts read through cordova...

my code javascript

```
for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++){

            $('#listaContactos').append("<li><h3>" + contacts[i].displayName + "</h3><p>" + 
                    contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value + "</p></li>");
        }

    }
```

my code html

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="listaContactos">

        </ul>
```

and result is something like this:

Célio Garcia

```
          Xénia Dembo
```

98765433211
                         Jussara Lemos
              97654332211

```
                     098763234622
```

PS: sorry I haven't 10 reputation to upload images

Comment: Post the image's url and someone can add it to the question.

Comment: Are you refreshing your jQM listview after appending?  Like `$('#listaContactos').listview('refresh')` ?  You'll need to do it after both your loops have finished, so after the first one.

Comment: [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/NRW9a/)?

Comment: What is the question, and how does it relate to the title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to enhance the style on your jQM listview after appending your data -

```
for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++){
        $('#listaContactos').append("<li><h3>" + contacts[i].displayName + "</h3><p>" + 
                contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value + "</p></li>");
    }
}
$('#listaContactos').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: @Juhana I had wrote why I do not added a image url here...